# Keyboard shortcut to move window to different monitor

Tags: release-loki, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm thinking of installing the latest elementary OS Loki on my computer.

I'm often in a dual monitor environment and I've grown accustomed to a keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu's Unity interface that allows  me to move an application from one monitor to the next using:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>

or

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>

Can I configure this in Loki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed elementary os loki and i've two monitors, a upper VGA monitor and down a notebook monitor.

I can moving the window with Shift+Super+Up and Shift+Super+Down, this works in default installation.

Comment: And is it the case I can re-map the shortcut to Left or Right instead of Up or down? @felansu

Comment: I'm using Up and Down because my VGA is above laptop screen. But now I configured side by side and can see [here](http://calmandev.com/Community/stackexchange/Peek%202016-09-17%2012-29.gif)