# Shortcut to shift window to second monitor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Currently running Elementary OS Loki, have set up keyboard shortcuts for tiling to left and right to be Shift+Super+Left/Right.

Sometimes this seems to push windows to other screens, however I feel like that's just a bug.

Read [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7879/keyboard-shortcut-to-move-window-to-different-monitor) that Shift+Super+Up/Down should do it by default, but that doesn't seem to be the case. If anyone can shed some light on this, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Under System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Windows, you can set shortcuts to tile windows left and right. I set these to use Shift+Super+Left/Right.

What I didn't realize is that by default you can use those keybindings to shift windows between monitors. (This option is not visible in that shortcuts page.) I found it in dconf-editor under:

org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings

Essentially I had the same keybinding for two separate functions. This seems to have caused a race conditon when working with multiple monitors as sometimes it would work shifting between screens the rest of the time it would just tile it.

I've now changed it so tiling is done with Shift+Alt+Left/Right and have found that shifting windows between screens now functions as expected.

Hope this is useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think that shift +super +left /right moves Windows between Desktops.

you can set up your own shortcut by going to keyboard >shortcuts > workspaces > move to left /right

let me know if that's it